# erro sendkeys não digita selenium - python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Olá, estou criando uma automação com o webdriver e panda no python, onde os valores das celulas de uma determinada planilha excel (xlsx) devem ser digitados na pagina do chrome. Entretanto,  em um determinado campo da página quando tento utilizar o send keys, ele simplesmente não digita. Trata se de um campo de valor financeiro, que por default fica com o valor "0,00" exibido.

Abaixo o código, onde o erro está no find element do valor :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import os
import pandas as pd



teste= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Documentos\teste.xlsx')


navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
action = ActionChains(navegador)
login="xxx"
senha="xxxx"


navegador.get("site") 

navegador.maximize_window()

navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Usr"]').send_keys(login)
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Pwd"]').send_keys(senha)
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btnSubmit"]').click()
time.sleep(1)

navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menu-bar"]/a[2]/img').click()
ddelement= Select(navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_tabSup"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/select[1]'))
ddelement.select_by_index(34)
time.sleep(4)

navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_divMnu"]/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/a[2]').click()
local= navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header_txt2"]')
action.context_click(local).perform()
navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gridLv_menu_itemMenu_0"]').click()

for column in teste.index:
    parte=teste.loc[column,'PARTE']
    time.sleep(1)
    navegador.find_element_by_xpath(' //*[@id="genSearch_is_cpSearch"]/input').send_keys(parte) 
    navegador.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/button ').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    navegador.switch_to.frame(navegador.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

    valor = teste.loc[column,'VALOR']
    navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=el__2019434]/input").send_keys(valor)
```

***O print do campo***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***O print da estrutura HTML***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei todas as possibilidades mas em nenhuma delas o campo é preenchido, inclusive com css selector.

Obrigado!

Comment: esta numa td, essa classe  "Field" só tem uma ?... no valor ali na imagem.. a tag class="Field" só tem nesse campo ?

Comment: A classe "Field" se repete 4x no html inteiro, mas dentro desssa td só tem nesse campo mesmo.

Comment: tenta fazer um filtro nesse td, para pegar esse field, no selenium da para pegar uma parte do html acho que assim fica mais facil para pegar a classe dentro do td.

Comment: tentei filtrar usando driver.find_elements_by_class_name mas ainda assim não obtive sucesso. Vc sugere algum outro tipo de filtro?

Comment: esse id no td é gerado um novo após alguns minutos, olhando novamente esse o xpath a um id com decimais diferente da imagem.. da uma olhada no id do td se ele é gerado um novo a cada carregamento da pagina.

Comment: Acabei de confirmar que fato o id muda toda vez que a pagina é recarregada, aparentemente sem um padrão. Existe alguma forma de anteciparmos o numero do id ou alguma outra forma p pegar o xpath?

Comment: Já passei por isso, faz um scrapy no td pegando o id e esse sequencia  poem no xpath.. assim "//*[@id={id_pegado}]/input"  usando f string

Comment: find_element.. pegando o td   e a função .get_attribute("outerHTML") captura a região.. ai só fazer um busca usando expressão regulares para pegar a sequencia do id e  esse ID só jogar no    navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="{id_capturado}]/input").send_keys(valor)

Comment: Eu nunca usei a função .get_attribute("outerHTML"), mas se entendi o resultado dessa função colocarei dentro do id do xpath p enfim usar o sendkeys? dessa forma, as sequencias futuras do id já ficarão corretas?

Comment: essa função faz o seguinte.  pega um campo por exemplo o <td> ... <td/> tudo que estara dentro dessa tag.. ai só pegar o retorno que vai ser o código html e fazer um grep para capturar o "id" e jogar dentro do xpath...     navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id={aquiOID}]/input").send_keys(valor)

Comment: tentei usando da seguinte forma:

codig = navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="el__43008"]')
codig2=codig.get_attribute("outerHTML") 

mas quando coloco print(codig2), me retorna: <input internalname="idValor" class="Field" style="text-align: right;">. Não estou compreendendo como pegar o id p incluir dentro do xpath

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso pode tentar usar

```
input = navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=el__2019434]/input")
input.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
input.send_keys(valor)
```

*mais compacto*

```
navegador.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=el__2019434]/input").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a' + valor)
```

Comment: testei mas também não deu certo. Como o id do xpath muda toda vez, não consigo nem chegar no campo.

Comment: Tente utilizar `navegador.find_element_by_css_selector('input.Field').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a' + valor)`.

Comment: não deu certo, ele continua pulando o campo e não está preenchendo o valor